# Entity Framework 5 Complex Type not resolving because type is an interface

Tags: frameworks, interface, entity, complextype

I have the following:

```
public interface IPerson
{
  string Name {get; set;}
   ... more attributes ...
  IAddress Address {get; set;}
}

public interface IAddress
{
  string Street {get; set;}
   ... more ...
}

public class Person: IPerson
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
   ... more attributes ...
  IAddress Address {get; set;}
}

public class Address: IAddress
{
  public string Street {get; set;}
   ... more ...
}
```

in my context class I define the following:

```
public DbSet<Property> Properties { get; set; }
```

in the `OnModelCreating` of the same context file I have

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PropertyMap());
modelBuilder.ComplexType<Address>();
```

When I go to the database Address is not part of Property. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I changed Property Address to be a type and it works. Would dearly like every type to derive from an interface.

Comment: I agree. Every literature you read on S/W development that has merit talks about how interfaces reduces coupling and inproves cohesivenes and then, you meet Entity Framework.The folks who developed EF had the right idea about entities however, the year is 2013 entities are now defined using interfaces.